# Azure Cosmos DB Transaction Isolation Level

Tags: transactions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a long-running query to a Cosmos container with SQL API that takes more than 10 minutes to complete. Is there a way to set the isolation level for the database to be "repeatable read" or "serializable" in order to avoid phantom read, [as defined here?](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/transaction-iso.html)

I know that we can set the consistency level for Cosmos DB, but it only applies to the read/write consistency between geological replica, not transaction isolation.

Comment: Why are you tagging this question for Cosmos but pointing to a PostGreSQL doc? It's not possible to have any operation in Cosmos take 10 minutes as the maximum time for any operation is 5 seconds.

Comment: I couldn't find related documentation under Cosmos doc... 
The 5 seconds time limit is a good point! I actually run the query from Power BI to query the whole database. Perhaps Power BI uses a different protocol when connecting to Cosmos.

Answer (score 0):

Try below [Best practices for query performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-query-metrics#best-practices-for-query-performance)

1. Partitioning and partition keys
2. SDK and query options
3. Max Item Count
4. Max Degree of Parallelism
5. Network latency
6. Indexing policy
7. Query execution metrics

Answer (score 0):

It does support.
Ref-[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency)